# How can I drop a specific packet from my netwirk traffic using Wireshark Ubuntu

Tags: wireshark, packet-analyzer

How can I drop a specific packet from my network traffic using Wireshark Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can configure firewall i.e. ufw in Ubuntu to block or allow particular type of traffic in Ubuntu or can also use iptables.

Wireshark cannot be used to block traffic as it is used as a network sniffer not a particular type of traffic blocker.

For more info on ufw see:

[Community ufw Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)